# How to work around excel date formats

Tags: excel, date, string-formatting, bloomberg

I have a problem with combining the contents of three columns into one for a description of a security to be used with Bloomberg's Excel API.  The Excel date format is getting in the way as it doesn't store the value the way it visually appears.  I have a column for ticker, one for coupon and one for maturity, formatted as date.  In the example below, I have two maturity columns, formatted as text & date respectively for illustrative purposes.   I have tried a combination of LEFT,MID,RIGHT, concatenations, ampersands, adding characters to the maturity, changing format, but nothing I have tried has worked getting around the Excel date format, as can be seen in the rightmost column.

Please see the column second from the right for an example of the desired result. If you have a formula or a macro that can do this, I would be very grateful.

```
Ticker  Coupon  maturity   maturity     Desired Result        Actual Result
ABC     4.000   44532      12/2/2021    ABC 4 12/2/2021       ABC 4 44532
ABC     2.250   43432      11/28/2018   ABC 2.25 11/28/2018   ABC 2.25 43432
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other values in the last column are strings, you can concatenate the maturity values that are dates with the text() formula, I believe.

Taking maturity as the third column (so you can omit the 4th column that converts the `Long` date value to a formatted date):

```
=A2&" "&B2&" "&TEXT(C2, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

Don't have excel at home, but that should do it.

Comment: Beat me to the punch, but I'll confirm that this method should work correctly :)